# How do I run code whenever the user opens a particular screen?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have the code below that I thought would run whenever the given screen is reached, i.e. whenever the user goes to this screen. This screen creates some temporary files for the user. I don't need them after the user leaves the screen, so I wanted to flush them everytime the user reaches this screen. However, the line with `await cleanupTempAudioFiles();` doesn't seem to be doing its job.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initialize();
  }

  void initialize() async {
    uid = auth.currentUser;
    filesInProgressFileDirString = systemTempDir.path + '/App/AppAudioFiles/FilesInProgress/';
    fileInProgressFileDir = await Directory(fileInProgressFileDirString).create(recursive: true);
    myRecorder = await FlutterSoundRecorder().openRecorder();
    myPlayer = await FlutterSoundPlayer().openPlayer();

    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 10),
    )..addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });

    controller?.reset();

    await cleanupTempAudioFiles(); //This code seems to not be running every time the screen is opened

    setState(() {
      sendableFileExists = 0;
    });
  }


 Future<void> cleanupTempAudioFiles() async {

    final dir = Directory(filesInProgressFileDir.path);
    final List<FileSystemEntity> files = await dir.list().toList();

    files.forEach((file) async {

      if (file.path == filesInProgressFileDir.path + currentAppFilename) {
        await file.delete();
      }

      if (file.path == filesInProgressFileDir.path + currentAppFilename + 'High.mp3') {
        await file.delete();
      }

      if (file.path == filesInProgressFileDir.path + currentAppFilename + 'Low.mp3') {
        await file.delete();
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: what's the reset function? cleanupTempAudioFiles function, is it even called? Put a print statement in there to check if the function is being called.

Comment: @KamrulHasanJony yes its `cleanupTempAudioFiles()`. It runs in the `initialize()` function. When I go to the screen, I see that it ran. If I hit back, then go back to that screen, I see that it ran again. However, if I create a temp file on this screen, then hit back, and then come back to that screen the files are still there.

Comment: It seems as though this `initialize()` function isn't running every time I land on this screen. So I'm looking for a way to run code whenever the user lands on this screen.

Comment: put a print statement at top of the initialize() and at the end of the function. It will help you determine if all await function has returned some sort of result.

Answer (score 0):

The initState() function is called when your object is put into the widget tree.  This is not the same as every time it is displayed. Navigator.pop() for example will show the screen without re-inserting the widget into the tree. see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html

To run every time the user sees a widget you should put the code into the build function or consider @overriding dispose(), didChangeDependencies() or
didUpdateWidget() instead to get the right part of the widget lifecycle.